# Restrict users to only create articles (and not categories) in joomla backend

Tags: backend, joomla1.7, user-permissions

How can I restrict users to only be able to create articles (and not categories) in joomla backend?
I'm using joomla 1.7

Answer (score 0):

2 things -

1. Update to 2.5
2. Rather than try to figure out where those settings are in the core ACL, just get ACL Manager. It makes using the built in ACL a breeze because it puts all the settings in one place in an easy to understand grid with easy to use filters. We put it on every site we build. It's $10 euro but well worth the price.